# Unity IoC in console application

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

Hi i have solution with oround 20 projects. My boostrap.cs file is located in UI. 
I had to add console application which will run as service so not in the contex of UI. This new console application has no idea about boostrap configuration and I would rather ovoid to create all instances manually. Is there any good approach to resolve this? Or kind of sharing bosstrap.cs across multiple projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reuse the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot), but [you shouldn't](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse).

(This is a Dependency Injection FAQ.)